# Como alterar texto de <legend> sem saber o id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma tag `<legend>texto</legend>` que não tenho Id e pode ter várias em uma página, gostaria de mudar com base no ID da div anterior

ex:

```
<div id="div1teste">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>texto</legend>
</div>
<div id="div2teste">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>texto</legend>
  </fieldset>
</div>  </fieldset>
```

Gostaria de alterar o texto da primeira ou da X `<legend>`
Tentei com jquery pegar todos os itens filhos da div
Algo como

```
$("#div1teste").childreen
```

Agora estou tentando criar um class="teste" na `<legend>` e tentar recuperar ele:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("teste")[0];
```

Mas ambos sem sucesso.
OBS: Só não posso inserir id nessa `<legend>` pois essa página inteira é criada dinamicamente e ficaria um pouco complexo colocar Id nela.

Exemplo no Jsfiddler https://jsfiddle.net/dorathoto/8yks4e5j/

Comment: Você pode percorrer todas os elementos e trocar os textos como desejar, veja se isso ajuda: https://jsfiddle.net/8yks4e5j/2/

Comment: abfurlan, show, melhor maneira, já percorro por todos, ótimo..

Comment: @abfurlan e se eu quisesse separar em 2 tipos, veja https://jsfiddle.net/dorathoto/8yks4e5j/3/ para um só alterar um tipo de legend e o outro legend seria possível?

Comment: Percorra os elementos filhos de cada div assim: https://jsfiddle.net/8yks4e5j/4/

Comment: Publiquei como resposta, já que te ajudou pode ajudar outras pessoas :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percorra todos os elementos e altere o texto conforme desejar, exemplo:

```js
$( "#alterarEnvolvido" ).click(function() {
    //percorre todos os elementos legend filhos da div #div_1Envolvido
 $.each($('#div_1Envolvido legend'),function(index){
   $(this).text('Envolvido :' + index);
  });
});
$( "#alterarVeiculo" ).click(function() {
 $.each($('#div_Veiculos legend'),function(index){
   $(this).text('Veiculo :' + index);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Envolvidos..
<div id="div_1Envolvido">
<button type="button" onclick="removeEnvolvidos('div_1Envolvido')" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
            <legend class="teste">Envolvidos </legend>
        </fieldset>
         <fieldset>
            <legend class="teste">Envolvidos </legend>
        </fieldset>
         <fieldset>
            <legend class="teste">Envolvidos </legend>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
       </div>
       <hr>
       Veiculos...
       <div id="div_Veiculos">
<button type="button" onclick="removeEnvolvidos('div_1Envolvido')" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
             <legend class="teste">Veiculo </legend>
        </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
             <legend class="teste">Veiculo </legend>
        </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
             <legend class="teste">Veiculo </legend>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
       </div>
       <hr>
       <input type="button" id="alterarEnvolvido" value="Alterar Envolvido 01">
          <input type="button" id="alterarVeiculo" value="Alterar Veiculos 01">
```

Answer (score 1):

Não pegue um elemento com a classe "teste" novamente dentro do mesmo. Atualmente, o `list.getElementsByClassName("teste")[0]` retorna undefined no seu código, já que não há nenhum outro elemento com a classe "teste" dentro do mesmo.

Para inverter isso, mude a linha:

```
list.getElementsByClassName("teste")[0].innerHTML = "Milk";
```

... para:

```
list.innerHTML = "Milk";
```

Answer (score 0):

Conforme o fiddle, você já selecionou o item `"0"` para a classe `teste` e atribuiu a variável `list`. Não há necessidade de selecionar novamente.

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("teste");
list[0].innerHTML = "Milk";
list[1].innerHTML = "Chocolate";
```

Ou, diretamente:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("teste")[0].innerHTML = "Milk";
document.getElementsByClassName("teste")[1].innerHTML = "Chocolate";
```

Espero ter ajudado.